# Excel - Indirect Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

another question regarding Excel Indirect Formula.

I have columns E1:J202 filled with one of the following:

- Green
- Amber
- Red

How can I use the indirect formula to count each of the above separately if a new row or column is populated?

Note: Everytime I add a new column in excel (ie: if I insert a new column [K]), I want the system to count the Green, Amber and Red cells from F1:K202 instead of E1:J202.

Comment: Does the rest of worksheet cells (below row 202 and to the right of column J) is empty?

Comment: Correct Akina. The rows beneath 202 and columns next to J are empty (for now)

Comment: Is VBA function usage safe for you?

Comment: Additionally - if you'll specify the whole worksheet in your counting formula then only used range of the worksheet will be processed.

Comment: I would rather not use VBA for multiple reasons.

Comment: Ok. Is your data solid (all cells in the range are filled) or there are empty cells? I know how to use formula for to define the address of the last cell in separate column or row, but not in worksheet...

Comment: All cells are filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(1:202,1,MATCH(1E+99,1:1)-5):INDEX(1:202,202,MATCH(1E+99,1:1)),"green")
```

It will find the last column with a true date and then create a range that includes it and 5 columns to the left.

If the "date' is actually text not a true date then use this:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(1:202,1,MATCH("zzz",1:1)-5):INDEX(1:202,202,MATCH("zzz",1:1)),"green")
```

Comment: Its perfect for columns E:J, however I want to get the count from columns J:E but if another column is entered to the right (Column K), then I want the count from columns K:F. In other words, I need six months back from the last column that populated with data (in this case column K and so on).

Comment: Are the values in row 1 numbers/dates or text?

Comment: dates and text. So columns A:D are text and Columns E onwards are dates (starting with April 2019 (column E) to October 2019 (column K))

Comment: Dates stored as strings or numbers formatted to look like dates? ie when you change the number format to general does a number appear or does the text remain the same.

Comment: number - the dates a formatted

Comment: Then use the first formula.

Comment: Perfect! Saved my day :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

sorry i miss read the question in my first answer.

Try using the below formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,5)&":"&ADDRESS(202,(COLUMNS($A$1:WZG1)-16221))),"green")
```

this will break down if you add a column to the left of `column A` or to the right of `column WZF`

Comment: Close! If a new column or row is inserted to the sheet, the formula counts the above criterias. However, If I add a new column, I want the formula to calculate the new column minus 5 rows before it.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole range cells are filled then use the below formula for to obtain the last cell in filled range:

```
=ADDRESS(COUNTA(E:E),COUNTA(1:1)-COUNTA(A1:D1)+4)
```

If all cells in A1:D1 are filled too the formula may be

```
=ADDRESS(COUNTA(E:E),COUNTA(1:1))
```

Use this address in your INDIRECT:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("E1:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(E:E),COUNTA(1:1)-COUNTA(A1:D1)+4)),"Green")
```

or, if all cells in A1:D1 are filled,

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("E1:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(E:E),COUNTA(1:1))),"Green")
```

Of course, you may use any another row and/or column for last cell detection.

Comment: Thanks Akina, I'm not quite sure which of the above to use as it I'm not familiar with the address and indirect functions.